# Clarification on neighborhood definition

Tags: general-topology

I read from wikipedia that a neighbourhood of a point $p$ is a subset $V$ of a topological space $\{X,\tau\}$ that includes an open set $U$ such that $p \in U$.

I would like to clarify, suppose that $p \in U$, but $p \not\in W$, if $V=\{U,W\}$, does $V$ qualify as a neighborhood of $p$ even if it includes the set $W$ which does not contain $p$?

Does this mean that if the topological space is $\mathbb{R}$, is it accurate to say that the set $\{(-1,1),(2,3)\}$ is also a neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: $(-1,1)\cup (2,3)$ is indeed a neighborhood of $0$, but your set is not.

Comment: By $(-1,1)$ do you mean open interval or ordered pair?  In any event, {$(-1,1),(2,3)$} is not a subset of $\mathbb R$

Comment: okay, $(-1,1)$ is open interval

Answer (score 1):

A subset $V$ of a topological space $X$ is a neighbourhood of point $p \in X$ if some open set $U$ exists such that
$$p \in U \subseteq V.$$
The point $p$ is not usually a subset of $U$, nor is $V$ typically a set containing two sets, one open. Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense as stated.

What I will say is that $(-1, 1) \cup (2, 3) \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ (and $e$ for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

$V=\{U,W\} $ is **not** a subset of  $X $, it is a subset of the topology  $\mathcal T $(assuming  $U $ and $W $ are open; otherwise it is a subset of $\mathcal P (X) $).